# Create git log from msbuild

Tags: msbuild

I have a strange issue with msbuild and git, i have a target in msbuild where i create a file that contains commits to git, but the target is not working when msbuild is running it... 
I toke a snippet from the task to show what i am doing:

```
<GitLogFormat>%25H:%25an:%25cd:%25B</GitLogFormat>
<GitLogPath>gitlog.xml</GitLogPath>

<Exec
  Command='&quot;$(GitRunner)&quot; log --full-history --pretty=format:&quot;$(GitLogFormat)&quot; > $(GitLogPath)'
  WorkingDirectory="$(GlobalRootPath)"      
</Exec>
```

This will output the command:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe" log --full-history --pretty=format:"%H:%an:%cd:%B" > gitlog.xml
```

If i execute this from a commandline (not msbuild) then the output of the gitlog file will look like this:

```
35b833f0133cee6bd749be6cc4dbb40c15ab1ff2:rewso:Sun Sep 14 12:16:51 2014 +0200:Main release_ContractManagement was commited local v: 0.17.2
0ca16d0c60768879cb876c1da8e9fb2e76ef6074:rewso:Sun Sep 14 11:29:16 2014 +0200:Main release_ContractManagement was commited local v: 0.16.2
fe14af5547f458dab069aa862c304e03136f0a94:rewso:Sun Sep 14 01:08:15 2014 +0200:Main release_ContractManagement was commited local v: 0.15.2
```

But if i do this from msbuild the output of the gitlog file will be:

```
an:B
an:B
an:B
```

How can i get the same output when i use msbuild??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The % character needs to be escaped twice. Had the same problem once and I don't remember why exactly it is needed twice; it might have something to do with Exec or underlying cmd treating % as character used for environment variables.

Anyway, this should do it:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <GitLogFormat>%25%25H:%25%25an:%25%25cd:%25%25B</GitLogFormat>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: The reason you need double `%` is because Exec task will write your command into temporary batch file. Inside batch files the rules for interpreting `%` characters are different from typing the same command in cmd.exe. To prevent interpreting % in batch files as parameter qualifier, double `%%` could be used. Alternatively, `^%` should work as well.