# Make MSBuild Exec Command with git log work cross-platform

Tags: .net-core, msbuild, csproj

I want to do this in my ASP.NET Core 2.2 project:

```
git log -1 --format="Git commit %h committed on %cd by %cn" --date=iso
```

But then as a prebuild step I included it in the csproj like this:

```
<Target Name="PreBuild" BeforeTargets="PreBuildEvent">
  <Exec Command="git log -1 --format=&quot;Git commit %25%25h committed on %25%25cd by %25%25cn&quot; --date=iso &gt; &quot;$(ProjectDir)/version.txt&quot;" />
</Target>
```

This works on Windows (if I understand correctly `%25` is a percent in MSBuild terms, and the double percent is a command line escape, so we have `%25%25`). It gives me this kind of `version.txt`:

```
Git commit abcdef12345 committed on 2019-01-25 14:48:20 +0100 by Jeroen Heijmans
```

But if I execute the above with `dotnet build` on Ubuntu 18.04, then I get this in my `version.txt`:

```
Git commit %h committed on %cd by %cn
```

How can I restructure my `Exec` element in a way that it runs on both Windows (Visual Studio, Rider, or dotnet CLI) and Linux (Rider, or dotnet CLI)?

Comment: To avoid similar limited I tried work with git commands via aliases.

Comment: Can you use [CodeTaskFactory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-roslyncodetaskfactory?view=vs-2017) on Ubuntu? It's more of a workaround if all else fails but I've used it before exactly to not have to deal with escaping things: it allows you to just write code inline in the msbuild file, in this case you'd use the Process class to launch git.

Comment: @stijn Thanks for the suggestion. That's.... an interesting workaround for sure! Don't think I can get away with that on my particular current project, but it was cool to learn about the feature nonetheless!

Comment: If no one else knows the proper syntax and the solution turns out to be two Exec statements each with a condition according to platform, you should consider raising this as an issue on https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild, it's not nice the escaping rules are different.

Comment: In doublequoted strings, the double percent escape may not always be required. So what is the result with `<Exec Command="git log -1 --format=&quot;Git commit %25h committed on %25cd by %25cn&quot; --date=iso &gt; &quot;$(ProjectDir)/version.txt&quot;" />`?

Comment: I found comment[1] which explains the reasoning behind the double escaping for Windows machines. Still remains the same issue for non-Windows machines


  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25908312/create-git-log-from-msbuild#comment40571006_25915814

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To avoid being "[DenverCoder9](https://xkcd.com/979/)" here is a final working solution:

There are two options both using the power of the `Condition` attribute.

**Option 1:**

Duplicate the `PreBuild Exec` element each with a condition for Unix like OS and one for non Unix like OS.

```xml
<Target Name="PreBuild" BeforeTargets="PreBuildEvent">
  <Exec Condition="!$([MSBuild]::IsOSUnixLike())" Command="git log -1 --format=&quot;Git commit %25%25h committed on %25%25cd by %25%25cn&quot; --date=iso &gt; &quot;$(ProjectDir)/version.txt&quot;" />
  <Exec Condition="$([MSBuild]::IsOSUnixLike())" Command="git log -1 --format=&quot;Git commit %25h committed on %25cd by %25cn&quot; --date=iso &gt; &quot;$(ProjectDir)/version.txt&quot;" />
</Target>
```

**Option 2:**

Add a property group to the `Directory.Build.props` file at the root level of you application and use it in your `PreBuild Exec` command.

```xml
<!-- file: Directory.Build.props -->
<Project> 
  <!-- Adds batch file escape character for targets using Exec command when run on Windows -->
  <PropertyGroup Condition="!$([MSBuild]::IsOSUnixLike())">
    <AddEscapeIfWin>%25</AddEscapeIfWin>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

```xml
<!-- Use in *.csproj -->
<Target Name="PreBuild" BeforeTargets="PreBuildEvent">
  <Exec Command="git log -1 --format=&quot;Git commit $(AddEscapeIfWin)%25h committed on $(AddEscapeIfWin)%25cd by $(AddEscapeIfWin)%25cn&quot; --date=iso &gt; &quot;$(ProjectDir)/Resources/version.txt&quot;" />
</Target>
```