# Git command formatting characters in msbuild are interpreted incorrectly

Tags: git, encoding, character-encoding, msbuild, csproj

I wish to add a property with the date of the current Git commit to the assembly info.

From my .csproj:

```
<Exec Command="git -C &quot;$(ProjectDir).&quot; log -1 --pretty=format:%ad"
      ConsoleToMSBuild="true"
      Condition="'$(GitCommitDate)' == ''">
    <Output TaskParameter="ConsoleOutput" PropertyName="GitCommitDate" />
</Exec>
```

Build output interpretation: `git -C "<project directory>\." log -1 --pretty=format:-­`

Output: `-`

Using raw format:

```
<Exec Command="git -C &quot;$(ProjectDir).&quot; log -1 --pretty=format:%aD"
      ConsoleToMSBuild="true"
      Condition="'$(GitCommitDate)' == ''">
    <Output TaskParameter="ConsoleOutput" PropertyName="GitCommitDate" />
</Exec>
```

Build output interpretation: `git -C "<project directory>\." log -1 --pretty=format:­-`

Output: `-`

Doubling `%` characters to escape them:

```
<Exec Command="git -C &quot;$(ProjectDir).&quot; log -1 --pretty=format:%%aD"
      ConsoleToMSBuild="true"
      Condition="'$(GitCommitDate)' == ''">
    <Output TaskParameter="ConsoleOutput" PropertyName="GitCommitDate" />
</Exec>
```

Build output interpretation: `git -C "<project directory>\." log -1 --pretty=format:%-­`

Output: `-`

This attempt worked, but it gets different details from those I want:

```
<Exec Command="git -C &quot;$(ProjectDir).&quot; log -1 --pretty=format:&quot;%%H %%cI&quot;"
      ConsoleToMSBuild="true"
      Condition="'$(GitCommitDate)' == ''">
    <Output TaskParameter="ConsoleOutput" PropertyName="GitCommitDate" />
</Exec>
```

Build output interpretation: `git -C "<project directory>\." log -1 --pretty=format:"%%H %%cI"`

Output: `2594b984b59b061dd714ed6a88fbee2907b30a05 2024-02-14T12:33:49-06:00`

So I tried adding quotes to my original attempt:

```
<Exec Command="git -C &quot;$(ProjectDir).&quot; log -1 --pretty=format:&quot;%%aD&quot;"
      ConsoleToMSBuild="true"
      Condition="'$(GitCommitDate)' == ''">
    <Output TaskParameter="ConsoleOutput" PropertyName="GitCommitDate" />
</Exec>
```

Build output interpretation: `git -C "<project directory>\ManagementConsole\." log -1 --pretty=format:"%­"`

Output: `-`

What am I doing wrong?

What details am I missing that would help solve the question?

(I know that `git show` would be easier, but it failed the build with an exit code 128, which I figured would be more difficult to solve without further details.)

The `-` characters in the output and at the end of "build output interpretation" is added manually because I could not copy and paste it from my build output. I do not know why, but I thought that might be a clue.

Comment: Rumors has it `%` must be [doubled and encoded as `%25`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54368280/make-msbuild-exec-command-with-git-log-work-cross-platform). Also https://stackoverflow.com/a/41312003/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmsbuild%5D+escape+percent

Comment: Are you trying to use [`%ad`](https://git-scm.com/docs/pretty-formats#Documentation/pretty-formats.txt-emadem) as the format? [`%` is a special character](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/special-characters-to-escape?view=vs-2022) because it is used to introduce an escape sequence. Did you test `%25ad`?

Comment: Not knowing what search terms to use, I did not find the answers of which this question is marked a duplicate before posting this question; therefore, I will leave this question here as a potentially useful duplicate redirect.